# Create specific div's inside another div

Tags: css

I am a newbie in css and would like to create the following:

[image]

I therefore created the following code:

```css
#outer{
  height: 420px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: green
}

#left_space{
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

#right_space{
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
   <div id="left_space">
   <div id="right_space">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This however gives me the following output:

[image]

Any feedback on what I should change?

Comment: Because these two divs are behind on the picture, but you've put them nested. Make them next to each other and they won't be nested.

Comment: Move the right_space div outside of the left_space div

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/f69L8epL/1/

You can do that by using `dispaly:flex` in css

And if you want to make a spaces you can use `margin`

I'm seeing you have a border for the boxes in the screenshot above if you want to do that you need to use `border: 1px solid #000;` for each box

If you are looking to make the green background to be full page you can just change the `width:100%;` to 100% in `#outer` class

```css
    #outer{
  height: 420px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: green;
      display: flex;
}

#left_space{
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
      margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

#right_space{
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
      border: 3px solid #000;
  background-color: yellow; 
      margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="outer">
 <div id="left_space"></div>
 <div id="right_space"></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="outer">
  <div id="left_space">
   </div>
  <div id="right_space">

  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
#outer{
  display: flex;
  height: 420px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: green
}

#left_space{
  flex:1;
  height: 100;
  width: 100;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px 10px 300px 10px;
}

#right_space{
  flex:1;
  height: 100;
  width: 100;
  background-color: yellow; 
  margin: 10px 10px 300px 10px;
}
```

You can visit this link: http://flexboxfroggy.com/
to learn more about flexbox :)